# How to create subpages automatically (for every user)

Tags: php, html

I am trying to automatically create a personal subpage for every registered user on my site. First, I tried to do a page with `$_GET` which worked because you could see the user profiles, but it's not a very good method because the URL isn't *"pretty."*

In observing other sites, as in `<a href="http://ask.fm/CharlieSocke">ask.fm</a>`, the profile name does not have any `$_GET` key/value pair(s) in the query string but the user subpage is automatically created, or another example is this site, which is formatted like: `stackoverflow.com/users/*TheUserID*/*TheUserName*`

How is this feature achieved dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be created with `.htaccess` *(if you are using Apache or similar)*.

For example, the real path of the personal page can be:

```
yourwebsite.com/userpage.php?user=john
```

With a `.htaccess` file you can configure to access using:

```
http://yourwebsite.com/user/john.html
```

With this rewrite code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)\.html$ /userpage.php?user=$1 [L]
```

An useful tool will help you: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Comment: So this /john.php is the same as /userpage.php?user=john only that the user see it so?

Comment: Yes, for example: http://agronomico.mx/programa.agro is equal to: http://agronomico.mx/view.php?page=programa